# How to export table structures and data from ms access as txt file

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I am new in ms access 
In mysql we can export table structure as create query like the following

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `audio_master` (
  `audio_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `audio_title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `course_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`audio_id`)
)  


INSERT INTO `audio_master` (`audio_id`, `audio_title`, `course_id`) VALUES
(1, 'java audio', 1);
```

Like this I need to take from MS Access. How I can export like this using ms Access or sql server

Any suggestions or answers highly appreciated

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using SQL Server Management Studio 2014:

1. Right-click on the database and click on **Tasks -> Generate Scripts...**
2. You'll be directed to an Introduction Page. Click **Next**.
3. Select database objects to script. You can either script the entire database or some specific database objects only. Click **Next**.
4. You'll be directed to the **Set Scripting Options** tab. Click the **Advanced** button.
5. Under the **General** category, go to **Types of data to script**.
6. Select **Schema and data** and click **OK**.
7. Select output type. Click Next.
8. Click Next then Finish.

You'll now have the `CREATE TABLE` statement together with the `INSERT` statements.

---

For SSMS 2008

1. Right-click on the database and click on Tasks -> Generate Scripts...
2. Select database objects to script. You can either script the entire database or some specific database objects only. Click Next.
3. Under the **Table/View Options** category, go to **Script Data** and set it to **True**.
4. Choose object types. Click Next and select the SPs, Tables or Views you want to script.
5. Choose from **Output Option**. You can either **Script to file** or **Script to New Query Window**. Click Next, then Finish.

Comment: there is no Advance button

Comment: but i got the create structure i need inser structure how i will get this

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio: 2008 i am using my system will support only 2008

Comment: How did this answer the OP question?  He wanted to generate the scripts in an ACCESS database, not SQL Server...

Answer (score 0):

Hi You have Import and export option. 
Please find the bellow link, like this you follow and change the source and destinations.

http://sqlvagalla.blogspot.in/search?q=import

[enter link description here](http://sqlvagalla.blogspot.in/search?q=import)